# Открыл свой проект 2013 года. Но MySQL уже изменился - выбрать данные

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Я уже не программист, но решил поставить на ноги старый проект.
Там присутствует алгоритм получения данных по номеру заявки, приходящей из GET-запроса по клику из списка (кликнул, открылось окно заявки с данными - редактируешь её):

```
$result = mysqli_query($db_link,"SELECT * FROM $userstable WHERE `number` = $id_zayv") or die("error 3!")
//этот запрос уже обновил до sqli
//но вот как быть со следующими ниже?
$fio = mysqli_result ($result,0,'fio');
$telephone = mysqli_result ($result,0,'telephone');
```

на PHP справочниках учат делать так:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db_link,"SELECT * FROM $userstable WHERE `number` = $id_zayv") or die("error 3!")
mysqli_data_seek($result, $id_zayv); //перемещает указатель на найденную строку
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$fio = $row['fio'];
$telephone = $row['telephone'];
```

Но почему-то такой код у меня лично не срабатывает. Да и выглядит он громоздко, по сравнению со старым.
PHP версия 7.1.22. mySQL 5.0.12
Подскажите что я делаю не так?

Comment: `mysqli_query()` + `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)`

Comment: и почитать как передавать параметры в запрос.

Comment: @teran Спасибо, это как раз и было необходимо - сокращение оператора while для получения одной строки $row.
Так как, я прочитав быстро php-net, использовал конструкцию с "while($row =" и не нашёл времени поэкспериментировать без цикла.